# Git - Merge in not updated branch

Tags: git, merge, git-merge, git-pull

Let's say that I have two branches one with new feature and another one of testing.

I would like merge the new feature in the test branch. The problem was that my local version of test branch was not updated with last changes and I forgot to update it before merge the new feature on it.

What happened is the following:

- Git merged the new feature in my local version of test branch.
- When I pushed the merge something similar to another merge happened, I think with the remote changes.

I think that a merge happened during the push because now I have the remote changes in my test branch.

Is it possible or happened something else?

The situation that I have now is that I'm not sure what exactly have in test branch. Basically I don't know what this mistake has involved.

I'm not sure that I understood well what happened, so I would like ask you to understand better what was happened and how I can fix this my inattention.

Comment: Merge never happens when you push, since there would be no way of resolving possible conflicts. Do you have any particular problems now?

Comment: Ok so why have I the remote changes in my branch now? Basically I don't know what i have in test branch...

Answer (score 1):

- When `local test` is not updated with `remote test` branch. Say, `local test` contains commit `A` and `remote test` contains commits `A & B`.

  ```
  local test:  A
  remote test: A -> B
  ```
- Merged `feature` branch with `local test`. Say, feature contains commit `P`.

  ```
  local test:  A -> P
  remote test: A -> B
  ```
- If you want to push `local test` you should face an error like `your test branch is behind origin/test`.
- Pulled `remote test` into `local test` branch.

  ```
  $ git pull origin test

  local test:  A -> B -> P
  remote test: A -> B
  ```
- Pushed `local test`

  ```
  local test:  A -> B -> P
  remote test: A -> B -> P
  ```

Answer (score 0):

- You already merged `new merge` in `test` branch locally [mentioned in first-bullet], so now you've `new feature` + `test` branch changes/commits in `test` branch.
- Now when you are pushing `test` branch, your remote `test` branch will also have `new feature` + `test` branch changes/commits in `remote/test` branch.

Comment: So, based on your second point, everything should be ok? And if unfortunately during the push i was conflicts with remote changes what would have happened?

Comment: Yes it's ok. When you are done with `test` branch, you need to pull `remote master` in your `local test` branch and if conflits occur then fix that here (`test branch`). Now Create pull request and merge `test` with master. Done!

Answer (score 0):

Probably you executed a `git pull origin test` (which integrated the remote changes of the test branch into your local one) before you pushed the changes. If there was some changes on `test` branch then you would get the message from git saying:

> Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.